# SQL Data Extraction and Date Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have data in a SQL Server table with columns:

```
Swipe_Date_Time, Emp_num , Emp_name, Direction
```

Direction represents "Entry" or "Exit".

Sample data:

[image]

Output expected: total day swipe-in inside office in minutes

Answer (score 0):

Condition:
There must be a row "Entry " before the row containing  "Exit"

> ```
> Create table Tbl01 (
>    Swipe_Date_Time datetime,
>    Emp_num Int, 
>    Emp_name NVarchar(10), 
>    Direction NVarchar(10)
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Tbl01 (Swipe_Date_Time,Emp_num,Emp_name,Direction) VALUES ('2018-06-01 10:34',1111,'XYZ','Entry')
> INSERT INTO Tbl01 (Swipe_Date_Time,Emp_num,Emp_name,Direction) VALUES ('2018-06-01 10:35',1111,'XYZ','Exit')
> INSERT INTO Tbl01 (Swipe_Date_Time,Emp_num,Emp_name,Direction) VALUES ('2018-06-01 10:37',1111,'XYZ','Entry')
> INSERT INTO Tbl01 (Swipe_Date_Time,Emp_num,Emp_name,Direction) VALUES ('2018-06-01 13:23',1111,'XYZ','Exit')
> INSERT INTO Tbl01 (Swipe_Date_Time,Emp_num,Emp_name,Direction) VALUES ('2018-06-01 18:39',1111,'XYZ','Entry')
> INSERT INTO Tbl01 (Swipe_Date_Time,Emp_num,Emp_name,Direction) VALUES ('2018-06-01 21:42',1111,'XYZ','Entry')
>
> select * FROM Tbl01
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Swipe_Date_Time     | Emp_num | Emp_name | Direction
> :------------------ | ------: | :------- | :--------
> 01/06/2018 10:34:00 |    1111 | XYZ      | Entry    
> 01/06/2018 10:35:00 |    1111 | XYZ      | Exit     
> 01/06/2018 10:37:00 |    1111 | XYZ      | Entry    
> 01/06/2018 13:23:00 |    1111 | XYZ      | Exit     
> 01/06/2018 18:39:00 |    1111 | XYZ      | Entry    
> 01/06/2018 21:42:00 |    1111 | XYZ      | Entry
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   Swipe_Date_Time AS Swipe_Date_Time_Exit,
>   Emp_num 
> INTO #T01
> FROM Tbl01
> WHERE
>   Direction = 'Exit'
>
> SELECT * FROM #T01
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Swipe_Date_Time_Exit | Emp_num
> :------------------- | ------:
> 01/06/2018 10:35:00  |    1111
> 01/06/2018 13:23:00  |    1111
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   Tbl01.Emp_num,
>   #T01.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit,
>   MAX(Tbl01.Swipe_Date_Time) AS Swipe_Date_Time_Entry
> INTO #T02
> FROM Tbl01 
>   JOIN #T01 ON Tbl01.Emp_num = #T01.Emp_num
> WHERE
>   Tbl01.Direction = 'Entry'
>   AND Tbl01.Swipe_Date_Time < #T01.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit
> GROUP BY 
>   Tbl01.Emp_num,
>   #T01.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit
>
> SELECT * FROM #T02
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Emp_num | Swipe_Date_Time_Exit | Swipe_Date_Time_Entry
> ------: | :------------------- | :--------------------
>    1111 | 01/06/2018 10:35:00  | 01/06/2018 10:34:00  
>    1111 | 01/06/2018 13:23:00  | 01/06/2018 10:37:00
> ```

> ```
>   SELECT 
>    CAST(#T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Entry AS DATE) AS Swipe_Date_Time_Entry_As_Day,
>    SUM( DateDiff(minute,#T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Entry,#T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit)) AS Swipe_Date_Time_Diff
>   FROM #T02
>   GROUP BY 
>     CAST(#T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Entry AS DATE)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Swipe_Date_Time_Entry_As_Day | Swipe_Date_Time_Diff
> :--------------------------- | -------------------:
> 01/06/2018 00:00:00          |                  167
> ```

---

**Result query**

> ```
> SELECT 
>    CAST(T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Entry AS DATE) AS Swipe_Date_Time_Entry_As_Day,
>    SUM( DateDiff(minute,T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Entry,T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit)) AS Swipe_Date_Time_Diff
> FROM 
>   (
>    SELECT
>       Tbl01.Emp_num,
>       T01.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit,
>       MAX(Tbl01.Swipe_Date_Time) AS Swipe_Date_Time_Entry
>    FROM Tbl01 
>       JOIN 
>       (
>         SELECT
>            Swipe_Date_Time AS Swipe_Date_Time_Exit,
>            Emp_num 
>         FROM Tbl01
>         WHERE
>            Direction = 'Exit'
>       )
>       AS T01 ON Tbl01.Emp_num = T01.Emp_num
>    WHERE
>       Tbl01.Direction = 'Entry'
>       AND Tbl01.Swipe_Date_Time < T01.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit
>    GROUP BY 
>       Tbl01.Emp_num,
>       T01.Swipe_Date_Time_Exit
>   )
>   AS T02
> GROUP BY 
>    CAST(T02.Swipe_Date_Time_Entry AS DATE)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Swipe_Date_Time_Entry_As_Day | Swipe_Date_Time_Diff
> :--------------------------- | -------------------:
> 01/06/2018 00:00:00          |                  167
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=05aba2d2bcc5902c87c2e8ba6a28d542)*

Answer (score 0):

Following query can give you the required output.

`SELECT t1.Emp_num, t1.Emp_name, t1.Swap_Date_Time AS Entry_Swipe_Time, ctbl.Exit_Swipe_Time, DATEDIFF(minute,t1.Swap_Date_Time, ctbl.Exit_Swipe_Time) AS ConsumedMinutes
FROM Sampletable t1 WITH(NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT t2.Swap_Date_Time AS Exit_Swipe_Time
FROM Sampletable t2 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE t2.direction = 'exit' and t2.Emp_num = t1.Emp_num
) AS ctbl
WHERE t1.direction = 'entry'`

Answer (score 0):

This is could be done with `LEAD()` function to get the next datetime for each `Emp_num`. Then, you just get the sum of those minutes and group them by date on each `Emp_num`. This will give you the total swipe-in inside office in minutes for each employee in each day.

the query :

```
 SELECT 
    SwipeDate
,   Emp_num
,   Emp_name
,   SUM(TotalSwipeMinutes) AS TotalSwipeMinutes
FROM(
SELECT 
    Swipe_Date_Time
,   Direction
,   LEAD(Swipe_Date_Time) OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_num ORDER BY Swipe_Date_Time) AS NextSwipe
,   LEAD(Direction)  OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_num ORDER BY Swipe_Date_Time) AS NextDirection
,   Emp_num
,   Emp_name
,   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Swipe_Date_Time, LEAD(Swipe_Date_Time) OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_num ORDER BY Swipe_Date_Time) ) AS TotalSwipeMinutes
,   CAST(Swipe_Date_Time AS DATE) AS SwipeDate
FROM OfficeSwipe
) D
GROUP BY 
    SwipeDate
,   Emp_num
,   Emp_name
```

The results :

```
|  SwipeDate | Emp_num | Emp_name | TotalSwipeMinutes |
|------------|---------|----------|-------------------|
| 2018-06-01 |    1111 |      XYZ |               668 |
```

The demo : [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90ef2/1)